# How to use smart part in Form based authentication site in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a site created in share point (WSS 3.0) which use Form based authentication. I have written a user control and I am trying to use it with the help of SmartPart, But it is giving me error saying that "can not access the path C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\5353\UserControls\". This is working file in windows authentication site. Please help me to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check to see if the account the app pool for your site is ran under has access to that path.